# How to maximize a MATLAB GUI figure/window on startup?

Tags: matlab, startup, figure

I am currently evaluating GUIs in MATLAB and was wondering how to maximize a GUI window on startup, without the need for user interaction. The function I am using is stated hereafter and works fine if called on a button press, but calling it in the figure's OpeningFcn won't help.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25471-maximize

Any help on some startup section to place the function call, which is executed after the GUI window has been drawn? I searched for solutions related to startup code in MATLAB GUIs, but there were no results to date.
Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: This might be of help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/3273

Comment: Actually this is kind of a comparable solution to the maximize issue, but not to my maximize on startup problem. I am not quite sure where to place the code/function call so that the window maximizes automatically after executing the GUI.

Comment: I added `set(hObject,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])` as the last line in the `function myGui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)` method.  When I started the GUI, it appeared at its maximum size.

Comment: I finally accomplished my aim through the use of a timer, calling the java function right after the GUI has been drawn. If desired, I will post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since many people seem to be interested in this and there is still no public solution, I will describe my approach:

1. In the `YourGUIName_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)` function, append the following lines:

   ```
   % Initialize a timer, which executes its callback once after one second
   timer1 = timer('Period', 1, 'TasksToExecute', 1, ...
             'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
             'StartDelay', 1);
   % Set the callback function and declare GUI handle as parameter
   timer1.TimerFcn = {@timer1_Callback, findobj('name', 'YourGUIName')};
   timer1.StopFcn = @timer1_StopFcn;
   start(timer1);
   ```
2. Declare the `timer1_Callback` and `timer1_StopFcn` functions:

   ```
   %% timer1_Callback        
   % --- Executes after each timer event of timer1.
   function timer1_Callback(obj, eventdata, handle)

   % Maximize the GUI window
   maximize(handle);

   %% timer1_StopFcn        
   % --- Executes after timer stop event of timer1.
   function timer1_StopFcn(obj, eventdata)

   % Delete the timer object
   delete(obj);
   ```
3. Declare the `maximize` function:

   ```
   function maximize(hFig)
   %MAXIMIZE: function which maximizes the figure withe the input handle
   %   Through integrated Java functionality, the input figure gets maximized
   %   depending on the current screen size.

   if nargin < 1
       hFig = gcf;             % default: current figure
   end
   drawnow                     % required to avoid Java errors
   jFig = get(handle(hFig), 'JavaFrame'); 
   jFig.setMaximized(true);
   end
   ```

Source of the `maximize` function:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25471-maximize